SqlModel - specify index type (B-Tree, Hash, etc.)
I'm looking at documentation for SQLModel. The python library is written by the author of FastAPI, so I'm eager to leverage the seamless db integration via SqlModel.
In the docs, he illustrates what an index is and how it works by graphically depicting binary search. So I think that it's reasonable to conclude that SQLModel can index on a given variable via B-Tree by default.
B-Trees (and binary search) make sense for range and inequality based queries. But equality or identity queries (name=='John') can be greatly sped up through hash-based indices. But if you could only support one index type, B-Tree obviously makes more sense than hash.
Here's an example
from sqlmodel import Field, Session, SQLModel, create_engine, select


class Hero(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str = Field(index=True)
    secret_name: str
    age: int | None = Field(default=None, index=True)

But suppose that I want to use a Hash index, can this be done through some SQLModel configuration?
Under the hood, SQLModel is built on top of SQLAlchemy. Perhaps as a backup, one should drop down a level and define the index type through SQLAlchemy. Ideally, building Db-provider specific solutions (ex: Postgres) can be avoided.

@snakecharmerb this doesn't look easy to do w/ SqlAlchemy, either. I'm not a Db architect or administrator, so I wonder if I'm overestimating how frequent hash-index use cases are / underestimating how effective binary tree indexes are...

SQLModel allows us to use SQLAlchemy's __table_args__ attribute in our model definitions. So, for
class Hero(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str
    secret_name: str
    __table_args__ = (
        Index("ix_hero_name", "name", postgresql_using="hash"),
    )

with
connection_url = "postgresql://scott:tiger@192.168.0.199/mydb"
engine = create_engine(connection_url)
SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)

SQLAlchemy generates
CREATE TABLE hero (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    secret_name VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
CREATE INDEX ix_hero_name ON hero USING hash (name)

The postgresql_using= option is ignored by other dialects, so
connection_url = "sqlite:///database.db"
engine = create_engine(connection_url)
SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)

produces
CREATE TABLE hero (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    secret_name VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
CREATE INDEX ix_hero_name ON hero (name)


Brilliant- Thank you for the answer!
I specified Postgres in my question but out of curiosity, could Index("ix_hero_name", "name", mysql_using="hash") be used instead?
I see that Postgres is preferred in a write-dominant environment but MySQL is preferred in a read-dominant environment.
https://aws.amazon.com/compare/the-difference-between-mysql-vs-postgresql/#:~:text=about%20LAMP%20stacks%20%C2%BB-,Performance%20requirements,data%20reads%2C%20MySQL%20is%20preferred.

Yes, you can even use both mysql_using="hash" and postgresql_using="hash" together.

Interesting! Would this create two independent databases, one Postgres and one MySQL?
